# How to send ajax request to request XML response to asp.net MVC 4 controller?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

OK so my asp.net MVC4 controller called **Home** is almost restful, so if I do this in Firefox or IE

```
http://localhost:1193/Home/?serialcode=123456789123321
```

It gracefully shows a page with a **code like 82434234** calculated using the serialcode above.

Now the controller supports returning XML data, tested and works with C# code. Now I'm stuck at the final step...ehm...sending a simple ajax request to get the code. This is what i have so far

```
                var xmlHttp;

                **//Problem 1: not sure what url should be like, given above Firefox
                // example ? Should the word Home , or index be in it?**

                var url = "index?serialcode=123456789123321";                    

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xml.dataType = "xml";

                **// Problem 2: this line doesn't do anything below**
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url , true);             

                xmlHttp.send(imei);
```

Any help GREATLY appreciated...thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify things and use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
  type: 'GET',
  data: { serialcode: 123456789123321 },
  success: function(responseData) {
    // TODO:
  }
});
```

Comment: after adding dataType: 'xml' to it, now i am getting an XML document back...Super!! I can use that.Thxxx

Answer (score 0):

Use Url.Action() to get the URL.  Pass the data by replacing your above code with a simple jQuery.ajax() call.